# Помогите удалить объект внутри массива

Tags: javascript, frontend, ecmascript-6

Имеется вот такой массив объектов. Необходимо удалить отзыв у модели с названием `modelName` с текстом совпадающим с переменной `reviewText`

`let reviewText = 'Text Dima'`

`let modelName = 'Camry'`

```
let models = [
   {
      "modelName": "Camry",
      "reviews": [
            {
               "authorName": "Dima Dima",
               "text": "Text Dima"
            },
            {
               "authorName": "Nastya",
               "text": "Text Nastya"
            }
      ]
   },
   {
      "modelName": "RAV4",
      "reviews": [
            {
               "authorName": "Dima Dima",
               "text": "Text Text"
            },
            {
               "authorName": "Nastya",
               "text": "Text"
            }
      ]
   },

]
```

Пытаюсь решить таким способом:

```
let newNewModels = models.map(elem => {
            if (elem.modelName == modelName) {
                let newReviews = elem.reviews.filter(item => item.text !== text);
                return newReviews
            } else {
                return elem
            }
        })
```

Не выходит...
Буду благодарен за совет, каким путём следует мыслить для решения задачи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let models = [
   {
      "modelName": "Camry",
      "reviews": [
            {
               "authorName": "Dima Dima",
               "text": "Text Dima"
            },
            {
               "authorName": "Nastya",
               "text": "Text Nastya"
            }
      ]
   },
   {
      "modelName": "RAV4",
      "reviews": [
            {
               "authorName": "Dima Dima",
               "text": "Text Text"
            },
            {
               "authorName": "Nastya",
               "text": "Text"
            }
      ]
   },

]

let modelName = 'Camry';
let text = 'Text Dima';

newNewModels = models.map(elem => {
    if (elem.modelName !== modelName)
        return elem;
          
    elem.reviews = elem.reviews.filter(item => item.text !== text);
    
    return elem;            
});
        
console.log(newNewModels);
```

Comment: Только при этом нужно будет иметь в виду, что в старой и новой структуре вложенные элементы будут одними и теми же, так что, возможно, нет смысла создавать такую псевдокопию.

Comment: угу.............)

Comment: Ответ помог. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно удалить в самой структуре, не создавая новую, можно так:

```js
let reviewText = 'Text Dima'
let modelName = 'Camry'

let models = [
   {
      "modelName": "Camry",
      "reviews": [
            {
               "authorName": "Dima Dima",
               "text": "Text Dima"
            },
            {
               "authorName": "Nastya",
               "text": "Text Nastya"
            }
      ]
   },
   {
      "modelName": "RAV4",
      "reviews": [
            {
               "authorName": "Dima Dima",
               "text": "Text Text"
            },
            {
               "authorName": "Nastya",
               "text": "Text"
            }
      ]
   },
];

const foundModel = models.find(model => model.modelName === modelName);
const foundReviewIndex = foundModel.reviews.findIndex(review => review.text === reviewText);
foundModel.reviews.splice(foundReviewIndex, 1);

console.log(models);
```